# Pass value of textbox from a report to another report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is there any way of getting just the value from one report to another?

I have two reports, on one of them I show the students who failed in their assignatures.On the report I only show the name of the student, his studentCode, the assignature where he failed and his note.

On another report I have the entire history of every student. On that report I show the name of the student, his studentCode, all of his assignatures with their notes and at the end the final grade of the student (Sum of all of his grades / # of assignatures)

So..I was wondering, can I get the value (Final grade) of the student from the second report to show it on the first report?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using a sub report to get to the second report.. if that is the case.. you can have a hidden parameter on your sub report.. and then on the original report, set the sub report property parameter.. pass the final grade from your original report to the sub report parameter.. you can then use that value in your second / sub report.. does that make sense?